# Xamarin.forms Android ListView - 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

So I've this ListView in my app which is instantiated once. The ListItem source is a List where I've a TemplateSelector which displays different cells depending on what kind of object that is stored in the list.

My problem occurs if I

1. Select a row in the list
2. Pop to previous Page
3. Push to my Page where I've my list
4. Select an item in the list
5. Crash.

I get the following error,

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
[MonoDroid] Parameter name: jobject
[MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallIntMethod (intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:343
[MonoDroid] at Android.Widget.AdapterView.get_FirstVisiblePosition () [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-16/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:866
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.SelectItem (object) <IL 0x0001f, 0x00080>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.OnItemSelected (object,Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00017, 0x00077>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1<Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs>.invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs) <0x0007b>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1<Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs>.invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs) <0x0003f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.OnSelectedItemChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,object,object) <IL 0x0001c, 0x000b7>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object,bool,bool,bool) <IL 0x000b9, 0x0032e>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object,bool,bool,bool) <IL 0x00213, 0x007b7>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.NotifyRowTapped (int,int) <IL 0x0004b, 0x0015b>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.ListView.NotifyRowTapped (int) <IL 0x0001c, 0x0009f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.OnRealItemClicked (object,Android.Widget.AdapterView/ItemClickEventArgs) <IL 0x00025, 0x000bb>
[MonoDroid] at Android.Widget.AdapterView/IOnItemClickListenerImplementor.OnItemClick (Android.Widget.AdapterView,Android.Views.View,int,long) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-16/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:261
[MonoDroid] at Android.Widget.AdapterView/IOnItemClickListenerInvoker.n_OnItemClick_Landroid_widget_AdapterView_Landroid_view_View_IJ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-16/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:194
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.09b491e2-61b2-4fd3-b387-65f476ed0dfb (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long) <IL 0x00029, 0x00047>
```

Any suggestions? Works fine on iOS! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you're using **Switch** inside the ListView's item, try **removing the Switch**. My issue disappeared when I removed the Switch.

I don't know your particular scenario but I **substituted the switch with image**

```
 var image = new Image {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
 };
 image.SetBinding( Image.SourceProperty, new Binding( "Image" ) );
 image.WidthRequest = image.HeightRequest = 15;
```

Where the Image is bound to these properties:

```
public static ImageSource Checked = ImageSource.FromResource( "checked.png" );
public static ImageSource Unchecked = ImageSource.FromResource( "unchecked.png" );
public ImageSource Image {
    get {
        if ( Selected ) {
            return Checked;
        } else {
            return Unchecked;
        }
    }
}

private bool m_Selected;
public bool Selected { 
    get{ 
        return m_Selected;
    }
    set{
        SetField(ref m_Selected, value, "Selected");
        OnPropertyChanged( "Image" );
    }
}
```

Where OnPropertyChange and SetField are from INotifyPropertyChanged members:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName ) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if ( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>( ref T field, T value, string propertyName ) {
        if ( EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals( field, value ) ) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged( propertyName );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that **if the Checked and Unchecked properties are not static the problem appears even with an image**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add all your controls in the OnAppearing function and set Content to null in OnDisappearing like this:

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
   public MyPage()
   {
      Title = "MyPage";
   }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
      List<string> listItems = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
      ListView listView = new ListView
      {
         ItemsSource = listItems,
         ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
         {
            TextCell textCell = new TextCell();
            textCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, ".");
            return textCell;
         })
     };

     StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
     stackLayout.Children.Add(listView);
     Content = stackLayout;

     base.OnAppearing();
  }

   protected override void OnDisappearing()
   {
      Content = null;
      base.OnDisappearing();
   }
}
```

A detailed description can be found on [blog.cloush.com](http://blog.cloush.com/?p=12)

Answer (score 0):

It is very had to find the reason in my case garbage collector help me to resolve 
`await Task.Yield()` is an option some time it don't working, in my case it resolve after collect the garbage

```
GC.collect();
```

remove the cache  when the page is displays